# WordPress Child Theme CSS Styling

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to work out some aesthetic glitches on my site:

[University Boulevard Registration Form](http://universityboulevard.org/enroll-online/)

This is a WordPress site with a Child Theme

I'm running into two problems.

The first is that I can't get borders to show around the input fields.

Line 479 of main.css is the code that seems to be affecting the border:

```
input, select {
       border: medium none;
       outline: medium none;
}
```

If I just disable it with firebug it the border shows nicely. My question is what, if any, CSS code should I use to simply disable line 479 in main.css?

I've tried

```
input, select {
       border: 1px!important;
}
```

in the child theme but that hasn't helped.

---

The second problem has to do with the padding in the drop-down menus for the "Participant Grade" field.

I would like it to display as without any padding.

The line that seems to be affecting this issue is line 1528 in main.css:

```
.widget-main select {
        padding: 20px;
}
```

If I add the modify the child theme as follows:

```
.widget-main select {
padding: none;
}
```

The code still goes off of the code on on main.css

The most confusing part of this is that if I firebug the page line 1528 in main.css it's crossed out. How can a crossed out line be affecting the page?

I would very much appreciate any help at all. I hope this question is detailed enough.

Thank you.

PS: I have screenshots but I can't put theme here because I don't have reputation points.

```
    They are hosted here:  http://ajjpreble.com/files/StackOverflow/
```

Comment: If you can upload your screenshots somewhere and add the link to your question, I'm sure someone will edit them into the question on your behalf

Comment: Screen shots are here:

http://ajjpreble.com/files/StackOverflow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your CSS:

```
.widget-main select {
    padding: 3px;
}
input, select {
    border: 1px solid #CCC; /* or the border color you want */
}
```

EDIT: Now I see your theme's core stylesheets are imported AFTER your child theme's style. Make sure to load it before or add !important to both styles I gave you

Comment: Hey Fabio, Thanks a lot!
What do you mean by "load it before"? Thanks!

Comment: it depends on how you built your site, but you probably have a style.css file loading the main theme's core styles. Like this: `@import url("../twentyfourteen/style.css")` Make sure all your NEW styles come after this. If you still have issues, do as I said, simply add !important and problem solved

Comment: Thanks Fabio,

I think I do have new styles coming after this. No matter, I added !important and it works. 

Thanks again!